# Load multiple values into a single string and put in mysql WHERE in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need help regarding the following situation, I want my user's time-line to only display the posts of whom I follow.
Here's an example of my SQL:

Post's table:

| postid | userid | info | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 000001 | p1 | 01/01/2022 |
| 000002 | 000002 | p2 | 01/02/2022 |
| 000003 | 000002 | p3 | 01/03/2022 |
| 000004 | 000003 | p4 | 01/03/2022 |
| 000005 | 000001 | p5 | 01/05/2022 |

User's follow table:

| followid | userid1 | userid2 | conf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 000001 | 000001 | Y |
| 000002 | 000001 | 000002 | Y |

Y = Following

I need my screen to only display the post's of who I follow, but when I will use the following code, I always return with the posts of a single person.

```
<?php
$local = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$bank = 'socialapp';
$connect = new mysqli($local, $user, $pass, $bank);
$idyour = $_SESSION['YourID'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM follow WHERE userid1 = '$idyour' AND conf = 'Y'";
$sql1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$detect = mysqli_fetch_row($sql1);
$result_user = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid = '$detect[2]' ORDER BY postid DESC LIMIT 0,5";
$sql2 = mysqli_query($connect, $result_user);
$detect2 = mysqli_fetch_row($sql2);
```

I have my code display posts that is working properly, but only this displaying the posts of a single users and not the two that I follow.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below query to get `users` list of users inside in `IN` operator.

```
$result_user = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid in (SELECT userid2 FROM follow WHERE userid1 = '$idyour' AND conf = 'Y') ORDER BY postid DESC LIMIT 0,5";
```

**Note: You Update inner query according to your need.**